# JSoup with userAgent prevent redirects

Tags: java, jsoup

I used JSoup for my web crawler

```
Connection con = Jsoup.connect("http://t.co/uySIPVNfgP");
Document doc = con.get();
String u = doc.baseUri();
```

The above gives the redirected url as the base uri

But with a User Agent set as follows:

```
con.userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6");
```

With the above does not follow the redirect.

As I know without a User Agent some websites does not allow its contents to be crawled.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that http://t.co/uySIPVNfgP does not responds with server side redirect when the user agent is set. But it sends the redirect in the html page as a meta redirect.

With jsoup I was able to catch the redirected url as follows:

```
Document doc = con.get();
Elements redirEle = doc.head().select("meta[http-equiv=refresh]");
String content = redirEle.get(0).attr("content");
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^.*URL=(.+)$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(content);
if (matcher.matches() && matcher.groupCount() > 0) {
     String redirectUrl = matcher.group(1);
     if(redirectUrl.startsWith("'")){
         /*removes single quotes of urls within single quotes*/
         redirectUrl = redirectUrl.replaceAll("(^')|('$)","");
     }
     if(redirectUrl.startsWith("/")){
         String[] splitedUrl = url.split("/");
         redirectUrl = splitedUrl[0]+"//"+splitedUrl[2]+redirectUrl;
     }
     return redirectUrl;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

see the [Jsoup docs about connection](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html). There you can find the followRedirects(boolean) method:

```
Connection con = Jsoup.connect("http://t.co/uySIPVNfgP")
    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
    .followRedirects(false);
```

Play with the parameters until you get the desired results.

Comment: But I want it to follow the redirect