# JSoup .followRedirects(true) does not work

Tags: jsoup

Does not follow (or at least does not get entire page content), how to solve that ?

There is no client side redirects I presume ...

```
    <meta http-equiv ...
```

[stackoverflow http-equiv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32892483/jsoup-with-useragent-prevent-redirects/32893778#32893778)

inside what I get down from this:

```
       Document doc1 = Jsoup.connect("http://e-uprava.gov.si/e-uprava/oglasnadeska.htm")
       .header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate")
       .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.21 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1042.0 Safari/535.21")
       .ignoreContentType(true)               
       .ignoreHttpErrors(true)
       .followRedirects(true)
       .timeout(600000)
       .maxBodySize(0)/*unlimited body size*/
       .get();
```

.

```
String url = "http://e-uprava.gov.si/e-uprava/oglasnadeska.htm";
final Connection connection = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(10000);
final Response response = connection.execute();
final int status = response.statusCode();
System.out.println(status);
```

status = 200

That is

> div class="subpage-container ...

is not filled with stuff that I see in browser.
[Checking for meta and javascript redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19038997/using-jsoup-connecturl-get-to-follow-javascript-redirects)  --> no usable results

Comment: I executed your code and it looks like, everything works fine. What is your exact question?

Comment: If your problem is solved, please consider accepting the the answer and don't forget to also up-vote it. If your question is still open, please be more specific of what the problem is now.

Comment: accepting the the answer and don't forget to also up-vote .... do tell where to do that ? I see no buttons, links, doh, I'm logged in.

Answer (score 2):

**explanation**:

Redirect is not the problem and `jsoup` loads the page correctly.

The problem is that the page is using `JavaScript` to dynamically load the content that you're looking for. While `jsoup` is just `HTML` parser, you cannot expect from it executing `JavaScript` and fetching the data.

**solution:**

If you open this page in browser and look at [developer tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) for all request that this page makes, you'll certainly find this one:

> http://e-uprava.gov.si/si/e-uprava/oglasnadeska/content/singleton.html?&type=-&rijs=-1&offset=155&sentinel_type=ok&sentinel_status=ok&is_ajax=1

Which contains all the data you want.

This solution is not ideal and any changes to page can break it. It would be much better to use browser emulators such as [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) or [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/)