# Jsoup not obtaining final redirected URL

Tags: java

Currently, I am trying to use Jsoup to get the final redirected url of this url: https://playoverwatch.com/en-us/search?q=Lolzword-1298. It should redirect to this url: https://playoverwatch.com/en-us/career/pc/us/Lolzword-1298, but the code below does not redirect the url.

```
String url = "https://playoverwatch.com/en-us/search?q=Lolzword-1298";
org.jsoup.Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect(url).followRedirects(true).execute();
System.out.println(response.url());
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

JSoup's `followRedirects` is for HTTP redirects ("server redirects"), and there is no such thing with the URL you are trying with.

Example with a shortcut URL to your own question:

```
String url = "https://stackoverflow.com/q/44769507";
Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect(url).followRedirects(true).execute();
System.out.println(response.url());
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44769507/jsoup-not-obtaining-final-redirected-url
```

This prints a different URL because of the HTTP redirect, see the headers:

```
% curl -I 'https://stackoverflow.com/q/44769507'
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44769507/jsoup-not-obtaining-final-redirected-url
...
```

If I try that with your URL, there is no HTTP redirect:

```
% curl -I 'https://playoverwatch.com/en-us/search?q=Lolzword-1298'
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: public;max-age=300
Content-Length: 104248
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
...
```

The "redirect" you see in your browser when you load the page happens much later, with JavaScript (if you disable JavaScript on that page, the page stays at its original location), and I don't think JSoup can catch that.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35653372/6730571) points to  [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) or [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) as alternatives that would be capable of executing JavaScript and allow you to obtain final URL.