# How to get "url" from a jsoup document?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jsoup

Suppose if I made a connection using the following code :

```
   Document document = Jsoup.connect(url)
                      .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.135 Safari/537.36")
                      .timeout(120*1000)
                      .followRedirects(true)
                      .get();
```

and now I want to extract the url with which I made connection with Jsoup, how can I do that ?

Comment: Do you want the redirected URL? See [java - Jsoup not obtaining final redirected URL - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44769507/jsoup-not-obtaining-final-redirected-url)

Comment: I'm not sure the document contains that information (I'm no Jsoup expert though). But don't you have access to `url`?

Comment: No no. I want the url with which I made connection with Jsoup. (the original url)

Comment: @Thomas The thing is that I am working with very large set of urls and performing various operations using jsoup. So, I don't want to make a new jsoup connection for every task, rather return same "document" if the url is same. Thus wanted to extract the url.

Comment: Why don't you store the url along with the document? Since you already need to make the connection once in order to retrieve the document that should be doable.

Answer (score 2):

The only url (in this case as a `String`) you can obtain from a jsoup `document` is using the [location()](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Document.html#location()) method, being aware of possible redirects that can bring an url different from the starting url:

> Get the URL this Document was parsed from. If the starting URL is a
> redirect, this will return the final URL from which the document was
> served from.